# How to enforce eager loading of associations when importing records using Searchkick with Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

For this setup with default (unspecified) `search_data`:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchkick
 has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy
 scope :search_import, -> { includes(:quantities) }

end
```

When importing all database records by running `Item.reindex`, each "batch" eager loads the quantities for all of the item ids as expected.

However, if I want to specify the index model document differently than the default attributes using the `search_data` method including the associated model data with something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchkick
 has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy

 def search_data
   {
     part_number: standard_part_number,
     category_id: category_id.to_i,
     content_source_name: content_source_name,
     standard_price: standard_price.to_i,
     locations: quantities.map {|q| [q.location_code,
       quantity: q.value.to_i,
       bins: q.location_bins]
     }.to_h
   }
 end

 scope :search_import, -> { includes(:quantities) }

end
```

where I am operating on the `quantities` using `map` to define a `locations` attribute, returning to import using `Item.reindex` I see that it not only eager loads all of the associated `quantities` each batch, but it also then loads all `quantities` per `item` with a hit to the database again for each `item` record it is indexing.

Am I missing something here to get `Searchkick` to eager load the `quantities` models and be able to customize the search data record using that already loaded associated model without it doing another pull from the database again per `item`?

**Update**
I've determined there is something interfering with the way the ActiveRecord normally responds to the method name used for the association with the eager loaded models **in our app** and may not be exclusively related to us using Searchkick, although it did reveal the issue. I am not sure what it is that is interfering at this time but it has something to do with the `target` method on the association. Perhaps a gem that is installed is causing this problem. I did manage to find a way to work around this (for now) using `item.association(:quantities).target` as a replacement for `item.quantities` and now when running the reindex it makes use of the already eager loaded `quantities` and doesn't hit the db again for each `item`

Answer (score 0):

> I see that it not only eager loads all of the associated quantities each batch

This is expected behaviour (and very likely performant), since each batch you will get different `quantities` to load, since they are connecting to different `items`, so you don't need to keep all quantities in memory.

> each batch, but it also then loads all quantities per item with a hit to the database again for each item record it is indexing.

This is actually unexpected, but my guess here is, that in one of the methods in `Quantity` (`#location_code` `#value` or `#location_bins`) or even one of the methods on `Item` that you call (`#standard_part_number`, `#category_id`, `#content_source_name`, `#standard_price`), there is some implementation, that requires reloading of records.
Without knowing the code of that methods it is purely speculative, but the presented part of the code looks fine.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure what is happening here. All of those other fields referenced for `Item` and `Quantity` are just attributes, not specifically defined methods. As a test I commented out all code in the `Quantity` model except the association definition and reduced the `Item` `search_data` to just `standard_part_number` and the `locations` : `quantities.map` and I still get the same unexpected results.

Comment: I further reduced the `Item` `search_data` method to `{
      standard_part_number: standard_part_number,
      quantities: quantities.map{|q| q.value}
    }` and still get the same unexpected loading of all associated `quantities` record per `item` record. This rails app was just migrated from rails 3 to rails 4. I wonder if there are settings or something in place left over from rails 3 that is signaling the already eager loaded model data to be ignored if this is not an artifact of `Searchkick`. Not sure yet. Need to figure out how to confirm through further investigation.

Comment: I've determined there is something interfering with the way the activerecord normally responds to the method name with the eager loaded models in the app. I am not sure what it is that is interfering but it has something to do with the target method on the association. Perhaps a gem that is installed is causing this problem. I did manage to find a way to work around this (for now) using `item.association(:quantities).target` as a replacement for `item.quantities` and now when running the `reindex` it makes use of the already eager loaded quantities and doesn't hit the db again for each `item`.